# Unable to apply discount on my Woo commerce discount plugin and settings link also is blurred

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am developing a WordPress, woo commerce site, and I am new to PhP scripting, I have created a basic Discount plugin with settings link for my woo commerce products, so when the plugin is activated I get a certain discount for all my products. But the problem is No discount setting is shown in my dashboard backend. I have copied the code from 2-3 websites. So unable to identify the problem with my code as no errors are shown.
If my code is wrong can anyone provide me the code which can do the following:

A sample WordPress plugin with a dedicated settings link for the plug
in and if once activated it should apply a certain discount to all the woo commerce products configured on the website.
Below is my code

```
<?php

/*  
* Plugin Name: Discounts  
* Plugin URI:  
* Description: A simple discounts plugin  
* Author: Taufeeq 
* Version: 1.0.0  
* Author URI:  
* License: GPL3+  
* Text Domain:  
* Domain Path: /languages/  
*/

class Discounts_Plugin {
    // Our code will go here
    public function __construct() {
        // Hook into the admin menu
        add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'create_plugin_settings_page' ) );
        add_filter('plugin_action_links_' . plugin_basename(__FILE__), 'codechief_settings_page');
    }
    public function create_plugin_settings_page() {
        // Add the menu item and page
        $page_title = 'My Discounts Settings Page';
        $menu_title = 'Discount Plugin';
        $capability = 'manage_options';
        $slug = 'smashing_fields';
        $callback = array( $this, 'plugin_settings_page_content' );
        $icon = 'dashicons-admin-plugins';
        $position = 100;
        
        add_menu_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $slug, $callback, $icon, $position );
    }
    public function plugin_settings_page_content() {
        echo 'Hello World!';
    }
}
new Discounts_Plugin();



function codechief_settings_page($links)
{
    $links[] = '' . esc_html('Settings', 'Discounts') . '';
    
    return $links;
}

if ( in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', get_option('active_plugins'))) {
    
    if ( ! class_exists('WC_Discounts_Woo')){
        {
        class WC_Discounts_Woo{//Within the class body
            
            //The 'get_user_meta' helps to get the save metadata for the logged in customer.
            
            public function show_user_discount($user) {
                ?>
<table class="form-table">
<tr id="show_user_discount">

        <th style="color:#0073AA">Discount</th>
        <td>
        <input type="number" id="show_user_discount" name="show_user_discount" min="0" max="100" value="<?php echo get_user_meta($user->ID, 'show_user_discount', true)  ?>">
        </td>
        </tr>
 </table>
<?php
}
//Add within the class body
public function show_discount_price($price, $product) {
    
    // $price = floatval($price);
    $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $discount = floatval(get_user_meta($current_user_id,'show_user_discount', true));
    
    if(!empty($discount)) {
        $final_price = $price - (($price*$discount)/100);
        return $final_price;
    }
}

 public function save_user_type_b2bwoo($user) {

        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_user') ) {

            return false;

            }

        if(isset($_POST['show_user_discount'])) {

            $show_user_discount = $_POST['show_user_discount'];

            update_user_meta($user, 'show_user_discount', $show_user_discount);

        }

}
            
            public function __construct(){
               
                {
                    add_action('edit_user_profile', array( $this, 'show_user_discount'), 10, 1);
                    add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', array( $this, 'save_user_discount'), 10, 1 );
                }
                //Add within the class constructor
                
                add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_price', array( $this, 'show_discount_price' ), 10, 2);
            }
                
               

}
                
            }
            
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: I have check your code and it seems that you must clear OOPs concept if you would like to develop a WordPress plugin based on OOPs concept. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Comment: Ok Thank you, I will look into it, but can anyone give me more precise answer as to where I went wrong.

Comment: You have used __construct function out of class. How that function will be executed? So better go with OOPs concept first.

Comment: ok I tried it but I was unable to complete the plugin tasks. So can you  edit and post the code it would be really helpful for me, My code should basically do these things. A sample WordPress plugin with a dedicated settings link for the plug in and if once activated it should apply a certain discount to all the woo commerce products configured on the website.